# PHP pasar de Objeto a Json

Tags: php

Me gustaria pasar de un object a json.

Estoy intentando hacer esto:

Object:

```
array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#8692 (1) { ["row"]=> string(121) "{"A":2,"B":1147,"C":"ROS, JO","D":"M","E":"0:51:00","F":"0:51:00","G":"M2","H":1,"I":"CLIA"}" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#8693 (1) { ["row"]=> string(121) "{"A":1,"B":1205,"C":"RI","D":"M","E":"0:49:52","F":"0:49:51","G":"M1","H":1,"I":"eS"}" } }

$data = json_decode($row, true);
```

> Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: Creo que el mensaje de error es autoexplicativo, estas tratando de decodificar un array. Si lo que intentas es pasar ese array a un String JSON, prueba con `json_encode()`. Si no es lo que intentas, da alguna explicación más en tu pregunta.

Comment: `json_decode` no es la función que busca, intente convertir a un array antes de utilizar `json_encode`,  algo así `json_encode( (array)$row )`

Comment: @MikelFerreiro Lo que quiero es pasar del object que tengo a un json pero no lo consigo.

Comment: Estás usando [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) (de JSON a PHP), lo que quieres es [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) (de PHP a JSON).

Comment: @Dev.Joel si pongo eso el resultado que me da es este: string(333) "[{"row":"{\"A\":2,\"B\":1147,\"C\":\"ROS\",\"D\":\"M\",\"E\":\"0:51:00\",\"F\":\"0:51:00\",\"G\":\"M2\",\"H\":1,\"I\":\"OIA\"}"},{"row":"{\"A\":1,\"B\":1205,\"C\":\"RI\u00c0\",\"D\":\"M\",\"E\":\"0:49:52\",\"F\":\"0:49:51\",\"G\":\"M1\",\"H\":1,\"I\":\"NED\u00c9S\"}"}]"

Comment: exacto, eso es un JSON

Comment: Y como puedo entrar en la posicion F por ejemplo?

Comment: El JSON (en este caso) es una cadena de texto. Si quieres entrar en la posición F no uses JSON, usa el objeto. Si tu array se llama `$objeto`, entonces podrías hacer `$objeto[0]["row"]["F"]` para acceder al elemento `F` del primer objeto del array `$objeto`. Si quieres hacer eso no necesitas JSON. Pero no tengo claro qué es lo que quieres entonces.

Comment: No entiendo por qué si es para leer el objeto lo quieres convertir 1º a JSON ¿? ¿Por qué no lo lees directamente como lo que es? ¿Qué ventaja sacarías de convertirlo a JSON en este caso?